# undefined reference when linking against libresolv

Tags: c++, autotools, glibc, libtool

I have a project that is a library that links against libresolv,
It works fine on recent distros: Ubuntu 10.x  Fedora 13, Mandriva
2010.1 but on Centos 5.x I get the following errors

glibc installed is: glibc-2.5-18.el5_1.1

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I./include -I/usr/include/postgresql  -O3
-ansi   -Wall -Wno-deprecated  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -MT testUpLog.o -MD
-MP -MF .deps/testUpLog.Tpo -c -o testUpLog.o testUpLog.cc
mv -f .deps/testUpLog.Tpo .deps/testUpLog.Po
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -O3 -ansi   -Wall
-Wno-deprecated  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0  -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib64
-L/usr/lib64/mysql -o testUpLog testUpLog.o libUpTools.la -lpq
-lmysqlclient -lssl -lpthread
libtool: link: g++ -O3 -ansi -Wall -Wno-deprecated -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
-o .libs/testUpLog testUpLog.o  -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib64
-L/usr/lib64/mysql ./.libs/libUpTools.so -lpq -lmysqlclient -lssl
-lpthread
./.libs/libUpTools.so: undefined reference to `__ns_name_uncompress'
./.libs/libUpTools.so: undefined reference to `__ns_initparse'
./.libs/libUpTools.so: undefined reference to `__ns_parserr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [testUpLog] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/UpTools-8.5.3'
make: *** [check-am] Error 2
```

library.la file contains:

```
dlname='libUpTools.so.0'
library_names='libUpTools.so.0.0.0 libUpTools.so.0 libUpTools.so'
old_library='libUpTools.a'
inherited_linker_flags=''
dependency_libs=' -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lpq
-lmysqlclient -lssl -lpthread'
weak_library_names=''
current=0
age=0
revision=0
installed=no
shouldnotlink=no
dlopen=''
dlpreopen=''
libdir='/usr/lib'
```

You can read configure.ac on

http://pastebin.com/hs5q21Rq

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: ptoato, my question is how can I compile against libresolv. Of course you don't see any "-lresolv". But even adding LIBS="$LIBS -lresolv" when running ./configure and libtool appending "-lresolv" dependency_libs at the end those errors appears. I mean: why do error output if I am linking against libresolv. I hope my question is more clear :) if you want I can paste my Makefile.am.

Comment: When you run configure, does it find the library?  You might want to add an AC_MSR_ERROR stanza to the 4th argument of AC_SEARCH_LIBS to ensure that it locates the library.

Answer (score 2):

If libUpTools uses functions lib libresolv, you need to say so:

`libUpTools_la_LIBADD = -lresolv` (of course -lresolv may be replaced by variables determined by configure etc.)

That way, -lresolv will end up in the .la file and also in the .so file (if you chose to build it) that you can run ldd on for verification.